# Safely awaiting two event sources in asyncio/Quart

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, quart

[Quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/) is a Python web framework which re-implements the Flask API on top of the `asyncio` coroutine system of Python. In my particular case, I have a Quart websocket endpoint which is supposed to have not just one source of incoming events, but **two** possible sources of events which are supposed to continue the asynchronous loop.

An example with one event source:

```py
from quart import Quart, websocket
app = Quart(__name__)

@app.websocket("/echo")
def echo():
    while True:
        incoming_message = await websocket.receive()
        await websocket.send(incoming_message)
```

<sup>Taken from https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/</sup>

This example has **one** source: the incoming message stream. But what is the correct pattern if I had two possible sources, one being `await websocket.receive()` and another one being something along the lines of `await system.get_next_external_notification()` .

If either of them arrives, I'd like to send a websocket message.
I think I'll have to use [`asyncio.wait(..., return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait), but how do I make sure that I miss no data (i.e. for the race condition that `websocket.receive()` and `system.get_next_external_notification()` both finish almost exactly at the same time) ? What's the correct pattern in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea you could use is a Queue to join the events together from different sources, then have an async function listening in the background to that queue for requests. Something like this might get you started:

```py
import asyncio
from quart import Quart, websocket
app = Quart(__name__)

@app.before_serving
async def startup():
    print(f'starting')
    app.q = asyncio.Queue(1)
    asyncio.ensure_future(listener(app.q))

async def listener(q):
    while True:
        returnq, msg = await q.get()
        print(msg)
        await returnq.put(f'hi: {msg}')

@app.route("/echo/<message>")
async def echo(message):
    while True:
        returnq = asyncio.Queue(1)
        await app.q.put((returnq, message))
        response = await returnq.get()
        return response

@app.route("/echo2/<message>")
async def echo2(message):
    while True:
        returnq = asyncio.Queue(1)
        await app.q.put((returnq, message))
        response = await returnq.get()
        return response
```